# Добавить прогресс-бар

Tags: jquery, html, css

В форме есть такие кастомизированные инпуты, с двумя кнопочками для увеличения/уменьшения значения http://jsfiddle.net/aEYMb/33/
Подскажите, как можно добавить к этому скрипту отображение прогресс-бара, добавляя/убирая к `ul.progress li` класс `selected` при увеличении/уменьшении значения в инпуте на единицу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```
    $(this).parents('.rate').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('.rate').find('li:nth-child(-n+'+count+')').addClass('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aEYMb/34/

Comment: Ага, спасибо, большое. А еще, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы если в инпут вводилось какое-то число, сразу 5, например, как можно выделить сразу 5 li в прогресс-баре?

Comment: change сработает только при потере фокуса. поэтому делайте на keyup http://jsfiddle.net/aEYMb/42/

Comment: Вот так вроде получилось http://jsfiddle.net/aEYMb/41/

Comment: @Yura Ivanov угу, уже тоже нашла это решение, спасибо)

Comment: ага. 41 и 42 ревизия одинаковые вышли )

Comment: А такой вопрос, вот у меня этих элементов li всего 12, если у меня в инпут будут введено большее число, чем 12, то с прогресс баром проблем не может каких-то возникнуть? так то оно вроде работает всё нормально.

Comment: да, проблем не будет. селекторы работают на вхождение. если элементы соответствуют селектору, значит будут отобраны. 13-й элемент искать никто не будет. См. также спецификацию по [nth-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ага, понятно, спасибо!